# how to get current date in MOMENT.JS Dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, salesforce, momentjs

> Using Salesforce 
>   apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Fullcalendarzip,
>   '/moment.min.js')}"

$(document).ready(function() {

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            editable: true,
        defaultDate:  '2015-12-12',
        editable: true,
       events:[    ]
    });
```

How to get today's date default but **defaultDate:  '2015-12-12'**,over here its hard coded how to get the default today's date.

Comment: Try `defaultDate:  new Date(),`

Comment: It worked Bro :) Tq so Much.. How to mark this a solved for u :) :) U ROCK

Comment: Well I need to post it as answer.. Then you can accept the answer with a **right mark** which will be on the left top of the Answer.. Also optionally you can upvote the answer..

Comment: What if i need to get the time also

Comment: `new Date()` will give you `date` and `time` which you can extract using some javascript techniques like `getTime` etc., You can **[find more over here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use Javascript's `new Date()` to get today's `date`.

`defaultDate:  new Date(),`